# Template file rewrites media files in django

Tags: python, django

I have vue app and django app. I build them separately and I use vue's `index.html` as a template.

When I go to the image directory. For example: `http://localhost:8000/media/posts/images/image.png`. Instead of getting the image, I get a static file. It happenss on development and production environment.

[image]

Here is my `urls.py` file. `TemplateView` responds to the root URL. I use `index.html` as a template. It comes from vue build.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ## I use index.html as template. It comes from vue dist directory
    re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I included vue build files in static files directories.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/home/sam/Documents/Projects/vue/flow/dist/static']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

And I use `index.html` from vue build as a template

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/home/sam/Documents/Projects/vue/flow/dist'],
        ...
    },
]
```

I tried different ways to fix it.

1. If I remove `re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))` line from `urlpatterns`, the image problem disappears. However I miss static files.
2. I tried to use `path` instead of `re_path`. Like this: `path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))`. In this case, I get both images and static files. But after refreshing the static page with `Ctrl + R`, I get 404 Django default page.

The question is how to get both images and static files without a refreshing problem as above?

Comment: Your index page somewhat rewrite your static/media files. You can leave default ```path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))``` url and add similar to this rule```re_path('^((?!media\/).)*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')```.

Comment: дуже дякую @YevheniiM. я нашел решение краще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `TemplateView` after `media` URL. It works fine.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += [re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

`urlpatterns = [path('api/admin/', admin.site.urls)]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: This answer is not right. You forgot about `TemplateView`